Cannot adapt type 'dict' using placeholder '%s' (format: AUTO) in SQLAlchemy ORM
I want check whether the particular email template is used in any other model instance and model Rule we have action(JSONB) while running query below query i'm getting error
I had added the sample query and error response
Sample response structure of action column
{
   "negative": [],
   "positive": [
     {
       "action": 45,
       "email_template_id": 1
     }
   ]
}



Query to check email_template
event_exists_subquery = exists().where(Event.email_template_id == EmailTemplate.id)

subquery = exists().where(
    or_(
        func.jsonb_contains(
            Rule.actions["positive"],
            func.jsonb(literal({"email_template_id": EmailTemplate.id})),
        ),
        func.jsonb_contains(
            Rule.actions["negative"],
            func.jsonb(literal({"email_template_id": EmailTemplate.id})),
        ),
    )
)

statement = select(
    EmailTemplate.id,
    EmailTemplate.name,
    case((or_(event_exists_subquery, subquery), False), else_=True).label("is_used"),
)
email_templates = (await request.state.db.execute(statement)).mappings().all()



Sample Error response
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg.ProgrammingError) cannot adapt type 'dict' using placeholder '%s' (format: AUTO)
[SQL: SELECT email_templates.id, email_templates.name, CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE events.email_template_id = email_templates.id)) THEN %(param_1)s ELSE %(param_2)s END AS is_editable, CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM rules 
WHERE jsonb_contains((rules.actions -> %(actions_1)s::TEXT), jsonb(%(param_3)s)) OR jsonb_contains((rules.actions -> %(actions_2)s::TEXT), jsonb(%(param_4)s)))) THEN %(param_5)s ELSE %(param_6)s END AS is_used 
FROM email_templates 
WHERE email_templates.deleted_at IS NULL]
[parameters: {'param_1': False, 'param_2': True, 'actions_1': 'positive', 'param_3': {'email_template_id': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x115d52ca0>}, 'actions_2': 'negative', 'param_4': {'email_template_id': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x115d52ca0>}, 'param_5': False, 'param_6': True}]

I had below packages:

python = "^3.11"
fastapi = "^0.111.0"
sqlalchemy = "^2.0.28"
psycopg = "^3.2.1"
psycopg-binary = "^3.2.1"

DB: Postgres

I had tried the below approach also to resolve the same but getting same type of error
subquery = exists().where(
                or_(
                    Rule.actions["positive"].contains(
                        [{"email_template_id": email_template_id}]
                    ),
                    Rule.actions["negative"].contains(
                        [{"email_template_id": email_template_id}]
                    ),
                )
            )


Rather than trying to construct a JSON literal in SQLAlchemy you could let Postgres do it using the jsonb_build_object function, which works like this:
so# select jsonb_build_object('a', 1, 'b', 2);
 jsonb_build_object 
════════════════════
 {"a": 1, "b": 2}

In your code, your conditions might look like this:
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
subquery = sa.exists().where(
    sa.or_(
        sa.func.jsonb_contains(
            Rule.actions["positive"],
            sa.func.jsonb_build_object("email_template_id", EmailTemplate.id),
        ),
        sa.func.jsonb_contains(
            Rule.actions["negative"],
            sa.func.jsonb_build_object("email_template_id", EmailTemplate.id),
        ),
    )
)

